"warning: 'x' may be used uninitialized in this function ", but only for -Os
I have this piece of code.  My minimal example reads:
//compile with:   g++ -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Os -c
extern void use_x(int x);
extern int get_x(bool &have_x) __attribute__((access(write_only,1)));

void fn(int a)
{
    bool have_x;
    int x;

    if (a >= 10) {
        have_x = a >= 20;
        if (have_x)
            x = 3;
    } else {
        x = get_x(have_x);
    }

    if (have_x) {
        use_x(x); //here, the warning reports
    } else {
        //use_x(x); //here, x IS uninitialized
    }
}

Note that variable a is there mostly so I don't have constants, as that would change things.
When I compile this with
g++ -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Os -c filename.c

I get:
filename.cpp: In function 'void fn(int)':
filename.cpp:19:17: warning: 'x' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

If I instead use -O1 or -O2 or -O3, I get no warning at all.  The code is such that if have_x is true, x will be initialized.  Thus, -Os is getting it wrong.  How do I get -Os to properly not report the warning, without adding additional code.
I have tried this with gcc 4.7.2 and gcc 10.2.1, so it seems a rather long-standing problem.

This is not too surprising.  It's impossible in general to detect uninitialized variables without some number of false positives and/or false negatives (halting problem), so it's heavily based on heuristics.  GCC doesn't attempt it at all when optimizations are off, and at higher levels it presumably does a deep enough analysis to discover that the variable actually is initialized whenever it's used.

One way to trick gcc into believing that a variable is initialized, while (usually) not changing the generated code, is asm("" : "=g" (x));

And note that by using -Wmaybe-uninitialized, you are explicitly inviting false positive reports.  It reports every use unless it can rigorously prove initialization, and by using a lower optimization level, you are tying the compiler's hands as to how hard it will work in finding such a proof.  One workaround would be to compile with -O3 -Wmaybe-uninitialized for linting, and -Os -Wno-maybe-uninitialized for release.

Actually, the asm() trick significantly changes the code.  I think it confuses the optimizer a bit.  The other option is to write #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmaybe-uninitialized"  Effective, doesn't change the code, but less satisfactory as it could mask other problems.
